# datasources with wildfly domain

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I’m trying to install two wildfly(master and slave) following the next guide:
WildFly 8 Cluster Howto - WildFly 8 - Project Documentation Editor

I want to run both wildfly servers in domain mode but after deploy the mysql driver using the “management console” and assign it to the “main-group” and “other-group” I can’t choose it to create a Datasource.

I have tested it several times but it has been impossible to find the solution. Can you help me, please?

Best Regards,

Frank

Comment: Which version of wildfly are you using ?

Comment: I'am use wildfly 8.2

Comment: try to install mysql driver using jboss cli

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, however, for the benefit of those still struggling with the same issue, I'd recommend using the CLI and make sure that the JDBC Driver is installed as a module on each Host Controller (that's a point where the domain installation typically fails).

Source: [Installing a Datasource on WildFly in Domain mode](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/configuring-a-datasource-with-mysql-on-wildfly)